# JSONObject Deserialization Does not Deserialize

Tags: c#, json, restsharp, json-deserialization

This stumps me. Here are my simplified C# class definitions:

```
public class Countries
{
    string TotalCount { get; set; }
    public List<Ctry> Country { get; set; }
}
public class Ctry
{
    string CountryId { get; set; }
    string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

The REST call I make succeeds and returns the following JSON which I can see in 'content' variable:

```
{"TotalCount":1,"Country":[{"CountryId":1,"CountryName":"USA"}]}
```

Here is my c# deserializing code:

```
var content = response.Content;
countryList =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Countries>(content);
```

After deserialization, I expect the country data to be in countryList object. However no data shows up in countryList! What gives? No exceptions or errors either!

Comment: What you see `countrList` variable while you're debugging? And also can you share all your request code?

Comment: @DanielLoudon You don't have to mark classes as `Serializable` for JSON serialization.

Comment: Daniel: I am using RestSharp client. The JSON I posted is returned by the call in response.content

Comment: @EmreSavcı I see TotalCount 1 and Country Id null CountryName null. TotalCount appears to be correct since there is only one Country that is being returned. However country data is not populated.

Comment: I reviewed this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605822/json-dictionary-result-deserialization-with-restsharp-newtonsoft-json?rq=1. My class names and property names match the JSON content. Still the object has no values!

Comment: @XamiYen Your property **names** match, but the types do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that JSON.NET defaults to camel-case property names. This is what your code is looking for by default:

```
{"country":[{"countryId":"1","countryName":"USA"}]}
```

You need to manually declare the JSON.NET property names for your model:

```
public class Countries
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "TotalCount")]
    string TotalCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Country")]
    public List<Ctry> Country { get; set; }
}
public class Ctry
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "CountryId")]
    string CountryId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "CountryName")]
    string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

I tested this and it works with your data.

As a side note, I declared all of the property names because I like to maintain manual control over the serialization and deserialization, in your case, you could squeak by with just declaring the multi-case words.

You can also fix this by adjusting the protection level for your properties, if you don't want to manually define property names:

```
public class Countries
{
    public string TotalCount { get; set; }
    public List<Ctry> Country { get; set; }
}
public class Ctry
{
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

This way JSON.NET can match the property names automatically if they are publicly accessible.

@Tom W - JSON.NET will automatically convert types when possible, int to string and string to int are fine.

Comment: I changed the protection level of the properties and that works! Good to know that JSON needs TLC!!